# getLastKnownLocation returns Null value

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing an android application in which I tried following code.
Also I have added all the persmission in my xml file.

```
public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

protected LocationManager locationManager;

protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

    retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCurrentLocation();
        }
    });        

}    

protected void showCurrentLocation() {

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}   

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}
```

But I am getting null value at getLastKnownLocation.
I am running my project on Samsung Galaxy Grand.
please tell me where I am doing mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seem perfect, I assume you are getting Null because there is no previous GPS value in your device. Do this, Load the application in your device, move to open sky, run the application, wait for 2 minutes. Come back to office inside, and then execute above code